# Consuming wcf service in coldfusion without generating proxy

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, coldfusion, proxy

We are consuming a WCF service using coldfusion. the wcf service does not expose metadata endpoint instead they share service contracts in dll and svcutil.exe generated proxy class.

Now, how can i consume the wcf service in coldfusion without generating proxy.? i see .net client can access that way by creating channel factory as given in the following url:

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/dhananjaycoder/accessing-wcf-service-without-creating-proxy/

i researched adobe help page:

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-78b4.html

but there is no clue.

what possibilities i have to consume the service?

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand the question. Let me see if I can figure this out:

No proxy would be involved unless you specify one. The client computer will invoke and consume the web service on the server without anything inbetween. It's a standard HTTP call.

You say you are connecting to svcutil.exe, a c# utility. So you seem to mean you have an additional layer between the two CF applications, correct? So svcutil.exe is acting as the "proxy"?